# Volume Mount Fails for AzureFileShare in minikube

Tags: linux, kubernetes, minikube, cifs

I am running locally minikube/docker on Windows 10 Enterprise. I try mounting a volume from azure fileShare as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
  kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret-fileshare
type: Opaque
stringData:
  azurestorageaccountname: <acount_name>
  azurestorageaccountkey: <access_key>
...
  spec:
      containers:
      volumeMounts:
        - name: mnt-volume
          mountPath: /mnt-path
      volumes:
      - name: mnt-volume
        azureFile:
          shareName: share-name
          secretName: secret-fileshare
          readOnly: false
```

I am getting the following error:

```
mount: /var/lib/kubelet/pods/9740442f-4bd2-4427-8074-fca5c2578563/volumes/kubernetes.io~azure-file/mnt-volume: bad option; 
 for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program.
 Warning  FailedMount  55s  kubelet, minikube  
 MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "backup-volume" : mount failed: exit status 32
```

Exact same yaml spec works just fine with Azure Kubernetes Service... Is there a way to get it working with minikube?

Comment: It seems that you are missing the nfs-common package. Can you try to ssh into minikube and do `sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y nfs-common` ?

Comment: nfs-common was already installed, still getting the same error message when mounting the share ...

Answer (score 0):

```
RUN apt install -y nfs-common
RUN apt install -y cifs-utils
```

add these two in your Dockerfile, create image and then push that image to dockerhub and then use that image in your k8s deployment.yml